# How come my guess the number game in JavaScript isn't working?

Tags: javascript

Whenever I enter a number it says the number is too low even if the number is way greater than the other number. When I enter zero or don't enter anything at all it says your number was too low. I don't get it i have looked over my code a bunch of times, but I still haven't found any problems.

Here is my code:

```
var answer = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
var number = confirm(Math.round(Math.random()*100));

if (number === answer) {
    confirm("You win!");
} else if(number < answer){
    confirm("Your number was too low!");
} else if (number > answer) {
    confirm("Your number was too high!");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to compare String to Number

Comment: @PaulS.: That's not the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var answer = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
var ai_nswer = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
var number = confirm(ai_nswer);

if (ai_nswer == answer) {
    confirm("You win!");
} else if(ai_nswer > answer){
    confirm("Your number was too low!");
} else if (ai_nswer < answer) {
    confirm("Your number was too high!");
}
```

Apart from `confirm` method you are using was not proper, the logic was also problematic. Your if conditions were wrong for high/low. You should store the value of your random answer in a temp value, and then confirm it, since `confirm` returns a boolean value, not the input value.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting `answer` to an integer value first using the `parseInt()` function;

```
var answer = parseInt(prompt("..."));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `confirm` function returns a boolean (`true` or `false`), so the `number` variable in the line below actually hold a boolean value.

```
var number = confirm(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
```

And that messed up your logic.

Simply change it to:

```
var number = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
confirm(number);
```

---

*Another notice*

`prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100");` returns a string, so to be 100% clear, you should cast the value to number:

```
var answer = Number(prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100"));
```

Answer (score 1):

the variables `answer` and `number` is not have the same kind, for convert use parseInt in the var `answer`, see my answer:

```js
var answer = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
var number = confirm(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
answer=parseInt(answer);
if (number === answer) {
    confirm("You win!");
} else if(number < answer){
    confirm("Your number was too low!");
} else if (number > answer) {
    confirm("Your number was too high!");
}
```